# Ionic avatar cant put the notification icon

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm used my university project for **Ionic -3** I'm try to create  sample image as 
Avatar to set of the small icon, but its cant do that correctly , any one know how to make correctly like this 
[image: Look sample image]

My [code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vpmmv5)

**my code**

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="assets/imgs/user.png">
      <div>
    <button id="notification-button" ion-button clear>
        <ion-icon name="notifications">

        </ion-icon>              
    </button>
</div>
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>Woody</h2>
  <p>This town ain't big enough for the two of us!</p>
  <ion-note item-end>3:43 pm</ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

**css**

```
 #notification-button {            
            position: relative;
            width: 42px;
            top:1px;
            right: 1px;
            overflow: visible!important;
        }


   #notifications-badge {
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            top: -3px;
            right: -3px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Underneath the answer, Before I saw your code...**

I don't have ion stuff, but I can help you with the css, is this kinda what you need?

`position: relative;` on the `.ion-item` and to get the small button on its right place, just put this `position: absolute; right: -5px; bottom: -5px;` in the `button`

```css
.ion-item{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.ion-avatar{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 3px #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="ion-item">
      <div class="ion-avatar">
        
      <div>
      <button id="notification-button">
        <div class="ion-icon">
          !!!
        </div>              
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Woody</h2>
  <p>This town ain't big enough for the two of us!</p>
  <p>3:43 pm<p>
</div>
```

**update**

When I played with chrome web tools a bit, I found this to get the button to the point you wanted it.

```
 #notification-button[_ngcontent-c0] {
        position: absolute;
        width: 42px;
        top: 25px;
        left: 30px;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
```

changed your `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` and changed the `top` and `right`, I'm not sure if your working responsive. But take a look if this helps. Otherwise, I know another good solution.

Comment: np, I also did an update which will maybe be a bit easier, didn't see your existing code till I published this.